# Rearrange Series values based on another Series values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv table with the following format:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({0: [0.6, None, None], 1: [0.3, 0.1, None], 2: [0.1, 0.5, None], 3: [0.2, None, 0.3], 4: [0.5, 0.3, None], 5: [0.4, 0.4, 0.1]}, index=["Base", "A", "B"])
>>> df
        0    1    2    3    4    5
Base  0.6  0.3  0.1  0.2  0.5  0.4
A     NaN  0.1  0.5  NaN  0.3  0.4
B     NaN  NaN  NaN  0.3  NaN  0.1
```

These values are hashes, uncorrelated with columns, but just simplified and left as `float` values.

I'm trying to rearrange the rows, so that equal hashes fall under same column.

`Base` row is like the header of the table, while other rows - `A` and `B` - are the ones to be rearranged to "match" the `Base` row.

The expected output is this:

```py
>>> expected_df
        0    1    2    3    4    5
Base  0.6  0.3  0.1  0.2  0.5  0.4
A     NaN  0.3  0.1  NaN  0.5  0.4
B     NaN  0.3  0.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
[Here's a link](https://pastebin.com/igN3XBFu) to the original DataFrame CSV.

EDIT:
Made question more clear.

Comment: see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the columns to integers and increment by `1`, then for all these integer columns, create the values and check if it's already in the original dataframe, if it is, then keep it, else use `NaN`; it can be done in list comprehension, for axis=1, finally apply `pd.Series` to convert the list into different columns

```py
df.columns=[df.columns[0]]+df.columns[1:].astype(int).__add__(1).to_list()
df[[i for i in range(1,7)]]=(df[[i for i in range(1,7)]]
    .apply(lambda row: np.array([i/10  if i/10 in row.values else np.nan for i in row.index]), 
           axis=1)
    .apply(pd.Series)
 )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
     0    1    2    3    4    5
0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6
1  0.1  NaN  0.3  0.4  0.5  NaN
2  0.1  NaN  0.3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

If needed, you can convert column names back to string.

**UPDATE:**

It's even easy to achieve the expected output after your updates to the question, you don't need to use the columns to get those values. Just check if a value in the `Base` index exists in the given row, if yes, keep it, else use `np.nan`, this way, the order from the `Base` index will match, finally you can apply `pd.Series` which will just result in dataframe with column name starting from 0 to number of columns in the dataframe, you may want to rename the columns at last.

```py
out = df.apply(lambda row: [x if x in row.values else np.nan for x in df.loc['Base']], axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
out.columns = df.columns
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
        0    1    2    3    4    5
Base  0.6  0.3  0.1  0.2  0.5  0.4
A     NaN  0.3  0.1  NaN  0.5  0.4
B     NaN  0.3  0.1  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Can you please make it more generic? I got three major problems: `KeyError` from columns (because 1 is missing, going from 0 to 2), `range` hardcoded (I have more columns) and, after fixing these, I still have `NaN` elements.

Comment: PS I added the CSV to the original post, if it can be useful

Comment: PPS now I saw the lambda function, but it is incorrect; values and columns are not related at all

Comment: @crissal, will update the answer accordingly.